# Instrument gives Memory leak while using NSbundle in a for loop

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode4, ios4

I was trying to remove the memory leaks in my app but i found out that while using the alloc NSbundle in a for loop it is giving me memory leak.

here is my code:-

```
in my class myFeed.m


for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)

    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

        NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary*)[topData objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *iconName = [temp objectForKey:@"feed_source"];
        NSString *imageName;
        TimeLineGrid *grid = [[TimeLineGrid alloc]initWithNibName:@"TimeLineGrid" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        CGRect frame = grid.view.frame;
       if([iconName isEqualToString:@"Youtube"])
           imageName = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Youtube" ofType:@"png"];;
         if  (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
         {
             frame.size=CGSizeMake(130, 130);
         }
        else
        {
        frame.size = CGSizeMake(180, 180);
        }
        [grid setDelegate:self];

        if (isConditionTrue) 
        {

            x = x - 200 - topFactor;

        }
        else
            x = x - frame.size.width;

        if (x < 0) 
        {
            x = 0;
        }

        frame.origin.x = x;

        frame.origin.y = y;

        grid.view.frame = frame;

        grid.view.tag = tagCount;

        if ([temp objectForKey:@"feed_item_nid"]) 
        {

            [tagToNIDMap addObject:[temp objectForKey:@"feed_item_nid"]];

        }




        if  ([(NSString*)[temp objectForKey:@"feed_source"]isEqualToString:@"Youtube"])
        {

            [grid.webView loadHTMLString:[self getYoutubeCode:(NSString*)[temp objectForKey:@"feed_item_url"] :grid.webView.frame] baseURL:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *  str = [[WebServiceController Initialize]parseHTMLData:[temp objectForKey:@"feed_item_body"] : @"//img"];
            NSURL * url  = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
            NSURLRequest * req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [grid.webView loadRequest:req];
        }

                    //[grid.view addSubview:grid.webView];
        tagCount++;
        [grid setHome:frame];


        grid.dict = (NSDictionary*)[topData objectAtIndex:i];
      //  grid.icon.frame=CGRectMake(grid.view.frame.origin.x, grid.view.frame.origin.y-20,grid.icon.frame.size.width,grid.icon.frame.size.height)
        grid.icon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

        grid.detail.text = [temp objectForKey:@"feed_item_title"];

         [scroll1 addSubview:grid.view];
        [imageName release];
        [grid release];
        [pool release];

    }
```

}

myGrid is an another class with a .xib which i am trying to load in myFeed class.
but if at the end of the loop i add `[grid release]` then the view of myGrid can be seen but the UiwebView present in myGrid does not show its data.
And the instrument is also showing memory leak at the line :

```
myGrid *grid = [[myGrid alloc]initWithNibName:@"myGrid" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

what i am doing wrong here...

Comment: Where did you insert `[grid release]`? It is needful

Comment: i have added the [grid release] code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't *doing* anything with all those `myGrid` objects (class names should start with a capital letter, by the way). Your loop creates a view controller, loads something into it's `webView` property, and then releases it, which is pointless.

I assume you are doing something with `grid` after this loop has finished - what is that? If you really need 20 different `myGrid` objects then you need to add them to an array or something during your loop, because at the moment you are just overwriting the value of `grid` every time your loop processes. If you remove the release statement then you will have a single `myGrid` object at the end of the loop, and 19 leaked instances from the other passes.

If you want a single `grid` object then create it before the loop begins - but it looks like that would just end up with a single object that is configured however you set it during the last iteration of the loop.

**UPDATE**

OK, now you've included your full code it is a bit clearer. You need to keep around each `grid` object. Create an NSMutableArray before your for loop (this should probably be a property of whatever object this code is in):

```
self.gridArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (... // your loop here
```

Within the loop, before you release grid, add the following:

```
[self.gridArray addObject:grid];
[grid release];
```

This prevents you losing the reference to each `grid` object except the last one, and stops you leaking memory in this code. You can later release or modify the objects in your `gridArray` as you see fit.

Comment: Yes if I dont release grid the data in the webView is shown perfectly. And when i tap on the grid it shows a UIpopOver. I need to load 20 grid because I want 20 youtube video thumbnails to be shown so that when i tap on the grid it shows me the popover with the video playing in it.

Comment: When do you make the grids visible? Can you include that code?

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I think this make super sense. give you +1